# update the datetime value of a table MS SQL from ASP.NET code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I've a table "user_info" with fields and datatypes.

> user_id || user_reg_date [datetime] NULL DEFAULT
>   (getdate()) || user_next_visit_date [datetime] NULL

here **user_reg_date** is default value, so the format is :: 2015-06-02 12:17:12.307

for the field, user_next_visit_date I've to update it from ASP.NET code, same format as user_reg_date.

```
string queryString = "UPDATE user_info SET user_next_visit_date = ???
    WHERE user_id ='" + user_id + "'";
```

how to set the value of user_next_visit_date [datetime] with the **current date time** in the same format as user_reg_date. I frequently face problem with datetime values inserting from ASP.NET to database.

Comment: Is it the milliseconds you´re having issue with? And since user_next_visit_date uses datetime, the format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS. So you need to have a look at the decmials in the end. Otherwise you could (if you so want the milliseconds) have a look at this, http://sqlhints.com/2014/02/23/how-to-get-time-hour-minute-second-and-millisecond-part-from-datetime-in-sql-server/ (you only need to add ":mmm"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DateTime has no format. Updating it is easy as cake with parametrized queries:

```
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand();
query.Connection = ...

// Parameters start with @
string queryString = "UPDATE user_info SET user_next_visit_date = @someDateVar WHERE user_id=@userid";
query.CommandText = queryString;

// Date parameter
SqlParameter dtPar = new SqlParameter("@someDateVar", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0);
dtPar.Value = DateTime.Now; // or any DateTime you have
query.Parameters.Add(dtPar);

// Id parameter
SqlParameter idPar = new SqlParameter("@userId", SqlDbType.Int, 0);
idPar.Value = user_id;
query.Parameters.Add(idPar);

// Execute
query.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This has the side effect that SQL injections are no longer possible.

In fact, I use this add-a-parameter part so often that I would recommend shortcuts which make them oneliners.

Comment: how to update the **user_next_visit_date** with current DATETIME value.

Comment: You should ALWAYS use parameterised queries, rather than building the SQL string manually. As the author of this answer says, it prevents SQL injection. It also means you don't have to worry about how to format values of various types so that SQL Server can understand them. If you want the `DateTime` from the server running this code, you can use `DateTime.Now`, and pass this as a parameter. However, if you want the SQL Server's date and time, use the SQL Server functions `getdate()` or `sysdatetime()` which return the current date and time in as SQL `DateTime` or `DateTime2` respectively.

Comment: @user4221591 I think my example shows exactly what you want to do: it updates `user_next_visit_date` with the `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 1):

To update with the current date just use `getdate()`:

```
string queryString = "UPDATE user_info SET user_next_visit_date = getdate() WHERE " ...
```

Remember to parametrise your queries as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime object and use like this

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now;
```

this dt object you can pass in your update statement.